# How to fix not found Android plugin in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I wanna create a new project in **Android Studio** and when it will finish and it shows me some error in bottom right dialog and when I click on error box.

Below is the error image

[image]

**Why it shows me this error?**

**How can I fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yesterday I have faced this problem and I did like this it resolved.

1. First uncheck the **Android Apk Support** and click on **OK**
2. then, Go to File --> Settings --> check on **Android Apk Support** and Click on **OK**.

I know it's a kinda weird but it works ...

Answer (score 1):

Click on Enable plugin for enable it. Then it will be fine.

Comment: When click on Enable button, show me window. and into this window show me some plugins red

Comment: Click Ok. Then Restart Android Studio.